# Symmetric difference of two Java arrays

Tags: arrays, java

I have two arrays

```
 String[] ID1={"19","20","12","13","14"};

 String[] ID2={"10","11","12","13","15"};
```

How can I get following answer while comparing above two arrays.

I want to exclude common elements while comparing above two arrays.

```
 String[] Result={"14","15","19","20","10","11"};
```

Comment: You need to explain *why* you'd want to get that result. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this literal homework assignment, or a generic guestion to learn the concept? Are the arrays always sorted? Give a bit of background please...

Comment: What is your logic and why you want to achieve this ?

Comment: I want to compare two arrays and exclude common elements..

Comment: Does order matter? For example, what should be the result of comparing `{14,10,11,12,13}` to `{15,10,11,12,13}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you want the union of the two sets (no duplicates, right?) minus the intersection:

```
Set<Integer> union = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ID1));
union.addAll(Arrays.asList(ID2);

Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ID1));
intersection.retainAll(Arrays.asList(ID2);

union.removeAll(intersection);

// result is left in "union" (which is badly named now)
```

(I changed your String to Integer, which seems to fit the data better, but it would work with String the same way)

Comment: This obviously won't preserve order or duplicates. If you need either, let us know.

Comment: actually i meant avoid duplicated values in that two arrays and print the result.

Comment: How can i print result biased on Your answer?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like XOR operation ;)

Please describe your needs a little bit more directly. Pseudocode:

```
foreach s in ID1 {
  if(ID2.contains(s)) {
    ID2.remove(s)
  } else {
    ID2.add(s)
  }
}
```

ID2 will contain your result. In assumption that there are not duplicates in both arrays.

Comment: Nice. The question was changed, so my answer does not match it at all now.

Comment: No worries but the idea is still relevant.