# Spam Message/Comment validation in Java?

Tags: java

I have a list of 35k words which are said to be spam words. I want to check a message/comment coming from font end contains any of this words. If yes then the message/comment will be considered as spam. How to efficiently implement this. Or is there any API/Jar available to checking spam messages?

Comment: If you would check if there are words in the text that match words in the list, it will take some time. This is however the simplest way of doing this. A difficult way of doing this, is training some AI with your dataset.

Comment: As @TVASO said, you can check if there are words in the text that match words in the list, but on 35k words it's can be too slow. To optimize this search you can use algorithms something like this: [trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement and loop calling to `indexOf()` method.

```
while(message.indexOf(35k_words[i]) == -1) { //Don't match
   code here...
}
```

Or you can use symmetric difference [Symmetric difference of two Java arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762164/symmetric-difference-of-two-java-array)

Comment: +1 for multithreading, try fork join pool https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html